# Can we upgrade WSL to latest, Ubuntu Kernel version and GCC,CLang compiler versions?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, windows-10, clang, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am currently using Windows10 Falls Creators Update.
Installed WSL using Windows Store Ubuntu App and it's showing that current Ubuntu version is **16.04**.

- How can it upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 or 18.04 ? should we be waiting for Microsoft release?
- How to Install latest **GCC/G++ 7.2**and **CLANG/CLANG++ 5.0**  compilers in WSL? or how can we upgrade current compilers to latest versions in WSL?

Comment: You can upgrade Ubuntu userspace (not the kernel) to latest one. See my GitHub issue [#2618](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2618). But not all features work well.

Comment: @Biswa thanx for the info'

Answer (score 2):

First of all, WSL does not come with a Linux kernel.  Instead it uses `LXCORE.SYS`, which is part of Windows.

I'm not intimately familiar with Ubuntu, but 18.04 is apparently the *bionic* release, which comes with glibc 2.26.  Some versions of glibc 2.26 are known not to work with `LXCORE.SYS` because all programs crash during startup.  I could not get coredumps to work on WSL, so I was not able to debug this further.  This means Ubuntu 18.04 may not work at all.  Ubuntu 17.04 uses glibc 2.24, so it is not affected by this particular problem.

To experiment with this (and to get access to more recent compiler versions), you can use `pbuilder` to create chroot environments and install Debian sid or buster (for example).

Comment: I installed clang 5.0 in WSL but, `clang++`  or `clang` commands not supported,even for gcc/g++ 7.2

Comment: Which build of Clang did you install?

Comment: Clang 5.0 version

Comment: I meant: You must have downloaded binary packages from somewhere. What did you do?

Comment: You need to put the installation directory on your `PATH`.

Comment: I also built GCC/G++ 7.2 as mentioned here - https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/05/04/building-gcc-wsl-windows-subsystem-linux/ 
Example shows for 7.1 but I download and install 7.2 , but WSL system default g++ 7.2 couldn't set as default compiler .

Answer (score 1):

I am using gcc on Ubuntu 18.04 WSL without any major problems.

`pedrinho@L-CGH-26502228:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.4.0-Microsoft (Microsoft@Microsoft.com) (gcc version 4.7 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014
pedrinho@L-CGH-26502228:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
pedrinho@L-CGH-26502228:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

You can install Ubuntu 18.04 directly from Windows 10 Store: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804/9n9tngvndl3q?activetab=pivot%3aoverviewtab

There is also a guide on Microsoft blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/07/09/upgrading-ubuntu/